# Shell: Run vim command using shell

Tags: shell, vim

How can I run the vim command ":retab" using a shell script to all the files in the current dir?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found something that could help you

```
for F in *.{c,h}pp ; do vim -c ":retab" -c ":wq" "$F" ; done
```

This should do what you'd like ;) maybe you'll need to change the for loop condition to your needs

Comment: Glad I could help, don't forget to mark the answer that the thread is solved ;)